# SDS hammer drill torque vs impact drill?

Tags: drill

I am looking for a new drill and need some advice on how much torque i need. I've read alot of stuff on the internet and is a bit confused.

I got 2 in mind. A Makita HP 2071 and a Metabo UHEV 2860

The Metabo is a true SDS hammer drill while the Makita is a impact drill both have 2 gears and varialbe speed and around 1000 Watt.

I would prefer to get only 1 drill due to cost and I could use a real hammer drill for concrete and chisle function. But i also want a drill that can cut large holes in wood and Im worried the Metabo don't have the torque needed.

The Metabo is rated at 18 nm torque and 35mm holes in soft wood while the Makita is rated 40mm in soft wood, they don't list the torque rating.

I've run into the problem due to my old B&D 400 Watt simply stalls when trying to drill holes using a bi-metal 55mm hole saw in some 25mm wood planks.

Looking at different drills i find the true SDS hammer drills often have much lower torque then their non SDS counterparts. But is it in reallity a non issue? and will i be happy about the performance of the SDS drill?

Comment: Neither of those is a true SDS hammer-drill. Those are drills with some hammering capabilities, as apparent by their layouts. Makita HR2811FT - that's how a hammer-drill looks like. Torque is non-issue for SDS only because nobody uses them for wood. You pretty much can't have good concrete-crushing and large bore sawing in one reasonable tool. Although any of those 2 will be much better than your 400W B&D, which is pretty much an advanced toy.